# Clear form reset cache after Ajax submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have form which has two buttons: cancel and submit.

Cancel calls only `reset()` function.
Submit calls external script with Ajax and after success Ajax call, it shows message that values are saved.

If I press cancel after success submit, the values are resetting to values before the submit. How can I keep the new values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it would be great if you share your code

Comment: You mean you want to avoid form cancelation while form is submitting?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you have two field in form

first name and last name.

---

then javascript code like,

```
var firstName="", lastName="";

// call this function on cancel button
function resetForm(){
      document.getElementById("firstName").value = firstName;
      document.getElementById("lastName").value = lastName;
}

// in ajax success
...

    firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    lastName= document.getElementById("lastName").value;
...
```

You can use object or array to store form value instead of separate variable firstName, lastName, etc.

Comment: @lingo, is this useful?